# Schedule Google Cloud Functions in Golang?

Tags: go, cron, google-cloud-functions

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) describes how to schedule Google Cloud Functions to run periodically. However, the example code is in JavaScript, and it seems that the configuration - registering the code that is called periodically - actually happens from the JavaScript, and makes use of JavaScript-specific SDKs. Is there any way to make use of the Schedule functionality from other Google Cloud Functions languages (in my case, Go)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will simply have to do what Firebase scheduled functions does internally, and:

1. Configure [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to send a pubsub message on your required schedule
2. Implement the [pubsub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) in the language you want

Comment: You can also trigger directly your Cloud Function with Cloud Scheduler: perform a simple HTTP request to your Cloud Function.